# extract application name from rawpacket

Tags: networking, packet, tracing, pcap

Sounds dumb, but can you extract application name from a packet/pcap.

For eg: If a packet destination is to chrome process, can you extract that information from packet?

Answer (score 0):

The process name or something like this is not part of the packet. In many cases one can look at the packet itself to determine the kind of application protocol using heuristics. One can also extract source and destination IP address and port from the packet. This together might be used to make an educated guess about the process which caused the packet though, but this guess might also be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

IP packet headers do not contain information about the process which caused them (if any); the IP packet payload may, though. The same packet may, at different times, be sent by different applications.

But you can (as root) ask the Linux kernel to which application the socket for that address belongs.

You can either grep through the output of e.g. `ss -ntup` or ask `ss` directly:

```
ss -anp 'src = 192.168.122.3:22'
Netid             State             Recv-Q             Send-Q                           Local Address:Port                            Peer Address:Port              Process                                      
tcp               ESTAB             0                  0                                192.168.122.3:22                             192.168.122.1:58552              users:(("sshd",pid=27425,fd=4))             
tcp               ESTAB             0                  0                                192.168.122.3:22                             192.168.122.1:40662              users:(("sshd",pid=7228,fd=4),("sshd",pid=7217,fd=4))
```